# Create sample application using spring version 2.5

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to start with new scratch application using spring 2.5, I want to integrate hibernate also in same project, can anyone suggest ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use Spring 2.5? It's an ancient version! I would suggest you check out Spring 4 along with Spring Boot. If are you are willing to go down that road, I can suggest a few links for you

Comment: Any documentation available for same?

Comment: Documentation for what?

Comment: For Spring 4 and Spring Boot, or any link available

Comment: I added an answer with plenty of links below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go down the Spring Boot road, there is plenty of documentation available:

First of all, check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql) part of the documentation.

Next you can check out [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) sample application, as well as [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa) sample application. Note that the aforementioned samples use Hibernate implicitly though the use of JPA.

You can also take a look at [this](http://kielczewski.eu/2014/04/developing-restful-web-service-with-spring-boot/) blog post.